# python: check if variable is defined and return its value or return other value

Tags: python, exists

I am trying to use this code

```
result = arr['key1'] or arr['key2'] or arr['key3']
```

explanation: 
I want to have value in result from either or dict keys .. the availability of keys depends on the environment. This is not about None .. only one of the arr keys might be defined ...

so is there a function or method like is_defined()

How do we do this in python ??

UPDATE

I'm having a new problem here .. 
CODE 1:

```
try:
   urlParams += "%s=%s&"%(val['name'], data.get(val['name'], serverInfo_D.get(val['name'])))
except KeyError:
   print "expected parameter not provided - "+val["name"]+" is missing"
   exit(0)
```

CODE 2:

```
try:
   urlParams += "%s=%s&"%(val['name'], data.get(val['name'], serverInfo_D[val['name']]))
except KeyError:
   print "expected parameter not provided - "+val["name"]+" is missing"
   exit(0)
```

see the diffrence in serverInfo_D[val['name']] & serverInfo_D.get(val['name']) 
code 2 fails but code 1 works

the data

```
serverInfo_D:{'user': 'usr', 'pass': 'pass'} 
data: {'par1': 9995, 'extraparam1': 22}
val: {'par1','user','pass','extraparam1'}
```

exception are raised for for data dict .. and all code in for loop which iterates over val

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
result = arr.get('key1', arr.get('key2', arr.get('key3')))
```

Comment: @Mark: then it will take `None`. That seems to be what goutham wants.

Comment: @chris thats exartly what I want .. just return a value.thanks for the solution